# Java swing.JFrame only paints content on resize of window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

I have the following program. It is supposed to print red text on a green ground. When the program opens, I only see the green background but not the red text on it. Once the window is resized and by this recalculated, the red text appears.

It works properly if I use a JPanel within the window and add a component there. If the colors are set in paintComponent then, everything works fine.

So where is the problem, if I draw on the JFrame directly. Am I missing a first "update" or something? It looks like there is some information missing on first draw of the window (the additional text) of which the program only becomes aware once the window is recalculated and redrawn.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PaintAWT extends JFrame {

    PaintAWT() {
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        // Set background color:
        // If you don't paint the background, one can see the red text.
        // If I use setBackground I only see a green window, until it is
        // resized, then the red text appears on green ground
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));

        // Set color of text
        g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));

        // Paint string
        g.drawString("Test", 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintAWT();
    }

}
```

Comment: For starters, you should be overriding `paintComponent`, not `paint`. And I personally recommend extending a `JPanel` instead of the `JFrame`. You also need a way to control the call to `repaint`, because by the logic of Swing the container will normally only repaint when it needs to (i.e. when you resize the window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should NOT be setting properties of a component in a painting method. Painting methods are for painting only. Don't use setBackground().

You should be setting the background of the content pane when you create the frame.

Whenever you do custom painting you should also be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the component.

You should also not be extending JFrame. You only extend a class when you add functionality to the class.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) fore more information and working examples. The examples will show you how to better structure your code to follow Swing conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You should move setBackground to constructor. Setting of background in paint method is a bad approach.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PaintAWT extends JFrame {

    PaintAWT() {
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Set background color:
        // If you don't paint the background, one can see the red text.
        // If I use setBackground I only see a green window, until it is
        // resized, then the red text appears on green ground
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);


        // Set color of text
        g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));

        // Paint string
        g.drawString("Test", 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PaintAWT();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not be extending JFrame to do custom painting. You should not be overriding paint().

Comment: How about changing the background color then? If I put it in the constructor instead of the paint method, it is fixed, isn't it?